# How to handle double tap with Accessibility Service?

Tags: android, accessibility, android-a11y

With an accessibility service, double tapping activate the last element focused by the accessibility service.

I just want to handle this event with my accessibility service but there is no listener/event for that. I only get two accessibility event of type "TYPE_TOUCH_INTERACTION_END".

I found a class in Android with a DoubleTapDetector but it's not accessible from the Android API:
[TouchExplorer.java (see inner class DoubleTapDetector)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/com/android/server/accessibility/TouchExplorer.java?av=f)

Comment: You can't handle double-tap events in an accessibility service. The events are captured by the accessibility framework, which simulates a DOWN/UP event pair.

Comment: I thought about a timer between two up event but it's really risky and don't think it's a good practice. I want to be sure that I can execute actions at the same time that an element is activated by double tap.

Comment: What about using CLICKED events as an indication that something was activated?

Comment: Because double tap does not only generate clicked events. By example with an accessible service, a double tap on textView will change the input focus and don't generate a click event. The Android doc says: "double-tap anywhere on the screen activate the focused item." But there's no global "Activate event".

Comment: can I see your .xml file for accessibility which is available in xml folder?

Comment: @SanjayKumaar Sadly, I don't have access to this project anymore. It was 8 years ago.

Comment: @probitaille you still need answer of this?

Comment: @Sanjay Kumaar An answer will always help someone who is looking for a similar question.

Comment: @probitaille there might be issue in accessibility .xml (accessibility-service) file. I'm sharing xml file in answer.

Answer (score 1):

This might be useful. Try this,

Add this in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<service
            android:name="com.example.Accessibility"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
                android:resource="@xml/accessibility_service" />
</service>
```

accessibility_service.xml in xml folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeViewFocused|typeViewTextChanged|typeViewClicked|typeWindowStateChanged|typeWindowContentChanged|typeWindowsChanged"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackGeneric|feedbackVisual"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagReportViewIds|flagIncludeNotImportantViews"
    android:description="@string/app_name"
    android:canPerformGestures="true"
    android:notificationTimeout="150">
</accessibility-service>
```